# Should I implement lazy loading based on a client cursor or a publication?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I need to confirm something. Considering that a publication returns a cursor, and the cursor is a handle on the related collection on client side:

As long as I don't `fetch()` the cursor documents, I don't have actually downloaded their data?

Does that mean that it could be a good approach to filter publishable documents in the publication and do the lazy loading of them client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As long as I don't fetch() the cursor documents, I don't have actually downloaded their data?

That's false. When the client subscribes to a publication, the server will send the entire matching set immediately, even if the client doesn't use the data for some time. That's why `fetch` on the client is able to return the documents synchronously (assuming the subscription is `ready()`).

If you don't want the client to download something, you have to filter it out in the publish function.

Comment: You can also track the state of the download with the reactive [`ready()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. I split my items by channel, each of them is filtered depending on if the user is member of the channel. It's gonna be a pain to lazy load each channel items in the publication (3 first items or a 9 item range).